# Sum of inverses of zeros of $L$-functions

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, l-functions, hadamard-product

Let $L(s)=\sum_{n\ge1}a(n)/n^s$ be a "standard" $L$-function, say converging
for $\Re(s)>k$, having an analytic continuation with no poles to an entire
function of order $1$ with functional equation
$\Lambda(k-s)=\omega\overline{\Lambda}(s)$, with
$\Lambda(s)=\gamma(s)L(s)$ for some factor at infinity $\gamma$, 
$\overline{\Lambda}$ corresponding to $\overline{a(n)}$, and
$\omega$ the root number. Assume that $a(n)$ is NOT always real. For instance
a nonreal primitive Dirichlet character.

Writing the Hadamard product $\Lambda(s)=ae^{bs}\prod_{\rho}(1-s/\rho)e^{s/\rho}$ allows us to compute $\sum_{\rho}1/\rho^m$ for all $m\ge2$ in terms
of the values of $\Lambda$ and its derivatives at $s=k$ (or $s=0$). But
unless I am missing something, I don't see how to compute $\sum_{\rho}1/\rho$
(which of course does not converge) understood as the limit for
$|\Im(\rho)|\le T$.

EDIT. In view of the comments, let me be more clear. Write
$$\Lambda(s)=ae^{cs}\prod_{\rho}(1-s/\rho)$$
where the infinite product is understood as the limit for $|\Im(\rho)|\le T$.
Of course $c=b+\sum_{\rho}1/\rho$.

I seem to have proved the following which must be very classical but need
a reference or confirmation that this is true (or false?), under the same
assumptions as above.

1) $c$ is always purely imaginary.

2) If $L(s)$ has an Euler product, then $c=0$.

3) If $L(s)$ does not have an Euler product, then it may happen that $c\ne0$.

Comment: $\frac{\Lambda'(s)}{\Lambda(s)} =\sum_{n\ge 2} b_n n^{-s}=s\int_0^\infty (\sum_{n \le x} b_n)x^{-s-1}dx$ converges for $\Re(s) > m$, from Mellin inversion $\int_{m+1-i\infty}^{m+1+i\infty} \frac{\Lambda'(s)}{s\Lambda(s)}ds=2i\pi \sum_{n \le 1} b_n=0$, with the residue theorem you expect your sum over the zeros plus a residue $\Lambda'(0)/\Lambda(0)$ (at first the sum over the zeros will be $\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{|\Im(\rho)| \le T_N} \frac1{\rho}$ where existence of $T_N$ letting us traverse the critical strip follows from the density of zeros)

Comment: What @reuns says seems classical for Dirichlet L-functions, but I'm not sure about the convergence issues. For instance, see (2) of Chapter 19 of Davenport, with $x=1$ (explicit formula). In the odd $\chi$ case, clearly $\psi_0(x,\chi)$=0 for $x=1$, which is $-\sum_\rho x^\rho/\rho-(L'/L)(0,\chi)+\sum_m x^{1-2m}/(2m-1)$, and the sum over $m$ will diverge at $x=1$. Of course, one doesn't have convergence of the integrals in the derivation of the explicit formula in the first place either.

Comment: On the other hand, Li generalizes his criterion to Dirichlet and modular form $L$-functions, and seems to give expressions for the desired case in terms of the expected logarithmic derivatives. I haven't figured out yet how he skirts convergence in his explicit formula usage. See Theorem 4 with $n=1$. https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1258138394

Comment: @MyNinthAccount I should have made clear the distinction between completed and uncompleted L-function : it is $\Lambda'/\Lambda$ plus  some $\Gamma'/\Gamma$ terms which is a Dirichlet series $L'/L(s)=\sum_{n\ge 2}b_nn^{-s}$, it is $\int_{(m+1)}\frac{L'(s)}{sL(s)}ds$ which is $=2i\pi \sum_{n\le 1} b_n=0$, but it is $\int_{(m+1)} \frac{\Lambda'(s)}{s\Lambda(s)}ds$ that we want to evaluate using the residue theorem, the difference is the integral of the $\Gamma'/s\Gamma$ terms

Comment: This question was re-asked and answered here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/370481/hadamard-factorization-of-l-functions so maybe it should be closed?