# Hadamard factorization of L-functions

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, l-functions, hadamard-product

I have already asked this question here in a different form, but really need an answer.
Let $L(s)$ be a "standard" $L$-function, say with Euler product, functional equation, etc...
(Selberg class if you like), of order 1, and let $\Lambda(s)$ be the completed $L$-function
with gamma factors. We thus have $\Lambda(k-s)=\omega\Lambda^*(s)$, where $\Lambda^*$ is
the "dual" Lambda function (example: if $L(s)$ corresponds to a Dirichlet character $\chi$,
$\Lambda^*$ corresponds to its conjugate), and $\omega$ root number of modulus 1.

Assume for instance that there are no poles. Since $\Lambda$ has order $1$ it has a Hadamard
product $$\Lambda(s)=ae^{bs}\prod_{\rho}(1-s/\rho)\;,$$
where the product is over the zeros of $\Lambda$ and understood as the limit as $T\to\infty$
of the product for $|\rho|<T$ (on purpose I do not use the more standard $(1-s/\rho)e^{s/\rho}$).

My question is this: do we always have $b=0$ ? This is trivial if $\Lambda^*=\Lambda$
(self-dual), otherwise the only thing I can prove is that $b$ is purely imaginary.
I have experimented numerically with some non self-dual $L$ functions attached to Dirichlet
characters, and it seems to be true.

Remarks: 1) I may have a proof using the "explicit formula" of Weil, but I am not sure of its
validity, and it seems too complicated. 2) I have a vague memory of Harold Stark mentioning this
result 50 years ago.

Comment: At least I'd agree that it is not trivial to prove what you want...

Comment: Is it clear that $\sum_{|\rho|<T}1/\rho$ has a limit as $T\to\infty$? I only know how to prove this in the self-dual case.

Comment: @Aurel: I think this is standard, but otherwise include it in the conjectural statement.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, your equality should be invariant under the map $s\mapsto 1-\bar{s}$. Does it help?

Comment: @Sylvain: yes, this proves that $b$ is purely imaginary, but nothing more as far as I can see.

Comment: I think the vanishing of $b$ would make the Hadamard product quite analogous to the one of the sine function used by Euler to solve the Basel problem, but for an aperiodic sequence of (real) zeros. So it may require the truth of GRH viewing those real zeros as the ones of the analogue of the Riemann Xi function. So an unconditional proof thereof seems unlikely.

Comment: @Sylvain: I would be happy to assume GRH if necessary.

Comment: I made a few back-of-enveloppe computations, and under GRH one has $\Lambda(s)=0\Longrightarrow s=1-\bar{s}$ hence $e^{bs}=e^{b(1-\bar{s})}$ which seems to imply, writing $s=x+iy$, that $2bx=b$ hence $b=0$ for $x\neq 1/2$ but it is to be taken with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe you are correct and $b$ is zero, although I find it inexplicable why this is not better known (certainly I didn't know it before).   Let's stick to a primitive Dirichlet character $\mod q$, but what follows should be applicable in general.  If we take logarithmic derivatives, then
$$ 
\frac{\Lambda^{\prime}}{\Lambda}(s) = b + \sum_{\rho} \frac{1}{s-\rho}, 
$$
with the understanding that the zeros $\rho=\beta+i\gamma$ are counted with $|\gamma|\le T$, and then $T\to \infty$.  Let's evaluate the above at $s=R$ for a large real number $R$, and focus just on the imaginary parts.

Now
$$ 
\text{Im} \Big( \frac{\Lambda^{\prime}}{\Lambda}(R)\Big)
$$
tends exponentially to $0$ as $R\to \infty$.  So let's look at the imaginary part on the right hand side, which is
$$ 
\text{Im} (b) + \lim_{T\to \infty} \sum_{|\gamma|\le T} \frac{\gamma}{(R-\beta)^2 + \gamma^2}.
$$
Note that
$$ 
\sum_{|\gamma|\le T}  \frac{\gamma}{(R-\beta)^2+\gamma^2} 
= \sum_{|\gamma|\le T}\Big( \frac{\gamma}{R^2+\gamma^2} + O\Big( \frac{R|\gamma|}{(R^2+\gamma^2)^2}\Big)\Big). \tag{1}
$$
To handle the error term, split into the terms $|\gamma|\le R$ and $|\gamma|>R$, obtaining that the error term is
$$ 
\ll \sum_{|\gamma|\le R} \frac{1}{R^2}  + \sum_{R<|\gamma|} \frac{R}{|\gamma|^3} \ll \frac{\log qR}{R}, 
$$
upon recalling that there are $\ll \log q(|t|+1)$ zeros in an interval of length $1$ (we will recall this more precisely next).

Now the main term in (1) can be handled by partial summation.  For $t>0$, put $N^+(t)$ to be the number of zeros of $\Lambda$ with imaginary part between $0$ and $t$, and $N^{-}(t)$ to be the number of zeros with imaginary part between $-t$ and $0$.   Then both $N^+$ and $N^-$ satisfy by the argument principle the well known asymptotic formula (for $t\ge 1$)
$$ 
N^+(t), N^{-} (t) = \frac{t}{2\pi} \log \frac{qt}{2\pi e} +O(\log (q(t+1))).
$$
Thus for all $t>0$
$$ 
|N^+(t) - N^-(t)| = O(\log (q(2+t))). 
$$
Now by partial summation
\begin{align*}
\sum_{|\gamma|\le T} \frac{\gamma}{R^2+\gamma^2} &= \int_0^{T} \frac{t}{R^2+t^2} dN^+(t) - \int_0^T \frac{t}{R^2+t^2} dN^-(t) \\
&= \frac{T}{R^2+T^2} (N^+(T)-N^-(T)) - \int_0^T (N^+(t)-N^-(t)) \Big( \frac{t}{R^2+t^2}\Big)^{\prime} dt \\ 
&= O\Big(\frac{T\log qT}{R^2+T^2} \Big) + O\Big(\int_0^T (\log q(t+2)) \Big(\frac{1} {R^2+t^2} + \frac{2t^2}{(R^2+t^2)^2} \Big)dt \Big)\\
&= O\Big( \frac{\log qR}{R}\Big),
\end{align*}
upon letting $T\to \infty$.

We conclude that the quantity in (1) is $O((\log qR)/R$, and so tends to $0$ as $R\to \infty$.

Comment: Another derivation appears in Corollary 10.18 of Montgomery-Vaughan; see also the discussion at the end of Section 10.3, where the proof is attributed to Vorhauer. Related to this is this question and the long discussion in the comments: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/343248/b-chi-l1-chi-l1-chi-dotsc

Comment: @PeterHumphries:  I recall that other MO question and the discussion, but I don't quite see that Corollary 10.18 is the same as this question.   Here one seems to say that $B(\chi)$ is simply $-\sum_\rho 1/\rho$ with the zeros counted as $|\rho|\le T$ (not just that the real parts match, which is obvious).  It's this part that I found surprising and don't recall seeing before.

Comment: I think you're right; I may have been overzealous. Is there a way to see this more directly via Corollary 10.18 though?

Comment: @PeterHumphries: I didn't see how (hence the write-up).

Comment: @Lucia: would you allow me to include a sketch of your proof in a book that I am writing (if you want your real name to be given, send me a private e-mail) ?

Comment: @HenriCohen:  Of course you are welcome to use the proof in your book.  Did you try asking Stark if he recalled this?   I can't believe it is not known somewhere.

Comment: I believe that a slightly different argument due to Ihara-Murty-Shimura ("On the log derivatives of Dirichlet L-functions at $s=1$") implies $b=0$ for (finite order) Hecke L-functions. It's Theorem 2 of the paper (subsecs 2.3, 2.4, pp. 4-5), and a key part of the proof is Weil's explicit formula.

Comment: @Alufat: Thanks for that reference!

Comment: @Alufat: so my own proof may be correct after all (but too long to post). Thanks for the reference.

Comment: Dear @Lucia, I am writing a paper where I reproduce your argument for (extended) Selberg L-functions in an appendix. It is the exact same argument up to very minor complications (which vanish once one spells the argument out) and it will be on arxiv soon. Should I just cite this m.o. question or would you prefer something else? Thanks!

Comment: @Alufat:  Please just cite this MO question.  Glad it was useful.